# Vite does not see exports

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, vite

i have a file which re-exports function from npm package

```
export * from "../lib/build/ui";

import * as _default from "../lib/build/ui";
export default _default;
```

default export works, and i can jump to to `/lib/build/ui` in vscode in `export default _default;`
but here `export * from "../lib/build/ui";` vscode does not see the file(can not jump)

versions

```
"typescript": "^5.0.2",
"vite": "^4.3.2"
```

Comment: may be issue in file's access, check your pid and gid

Comment: solved! problem was that there were file called ui.js and ui folder and the same directory, vite was looking at wrong destination